# C++ unusual use of placement new into NULL

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, placement-new

In [the following C++98 statement](https://github.com/aneto0/MARTe2/blob/master/Source/Core/Scheduler/L5GAMs/GAMScheduler.cpp#L182):

```
multiThreadService[nextBuffer] = new (NULL) MultiThreadService(binder);
```

Would it be correct to say:

1. this is "placement new",
2. the object will be created (at NULL, somehow?) and thrown away, and
3. `multiThreadService[nextBuffer]` will now be NULL?

I was also told this could be UB - is that the case?

Comment: [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) says it's UB: *If a null pointer is passed as the argument to a non-allocating placement new-expression, which makes the selected standard non-allocating placement allocation function return a null pointer, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: Yes, it's a "placement new".   It's also a serious code smell.   The behaviour will generally be undefined.   There is no `someArray` in your example, so your third point doesn't make sense.

Comment: This can be well defined with a custom operator new overload but has serious code smell. The NULL would be a dummy so the overloaded new is choosen. A better way is to define a sentinel value in MultiThreadService and use that as dummy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is not necessarily calling the global non-allocating placement-new `operator new` overload `void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr)` (What is commonly meant by "*placement new*".)

Because the new-expression is not qualified as `::new`, it may prefer an in-class overload of `operator new` if a suitable one exists and furthermore the type of `NULL` is not `void*`, but either `std::nullptr_t` or an integral type (the former not being possible in C++98). Therefore there are some potential alternative results of overload resolution even in the global case.

Searching the project for `operator new` overloads one can find at least one possible candidate at https://github.com/aneto0/MARTe2/blob/master/Source/Core/BareMetal/L2Objects/CLASSREGISTER.h#L85, which seems to return a valid pointer even if the placement argument (second function argument) is a null pointer.

If the selected overload is really the global non-allocating placement-new `operator new`, then it was basically a noop in C++98 resulting in a null pointer. `new` expressions were required to not do any initialization if `operator new` returns a null pointer.

However this was changed with [CWG 1748](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1748.html) and now the behavior is undefined if the global non-allocating placement-new `operator new` returns a null pointer value. This may have been considered a defect against C++98 as well (I don't know), in which case `-std=c++98` will not prevent the undefined behavior on a current compiler.

Comment: Ah... forgot about the existence of operator overloading. *facepalm*

Comment: There is also the wrinkle that the type of `NULL` is unspecified (it's a null pointer constant, which is not guaranteed to have a pointer type).   That makes it problematic determining which overloaded placement `operator new()` would be called, particularly with different compilers.

Comment: @Peter, ah, this project has a custom NULL that's void* typed, so at least _that_ issue is avoided (there are many others...)

Comment: @APerson _That_ sounds like UB.

Comment: @Peter I have extended the answer with some details on the overload resolution.

Comment: @user17732522 See https://github.com/aneto0/MARTe2/blob/master/Source/Core/BareMetal/L0Types/CompilerTypes.h#L88-L95 for the NULL. As you may have guessed I'm a bit out of my depth here...

Comment: @APerson That does look weird. Even assuming defining `NULL` is allowed, then the resulting type will not match what the C++ standard requires and in fact, because implicit conversions from `void*` to other pointer types are forbidden in C++ (but not C), this would make e.g. the `operator new` overload I linked above non-viable.

Comment: @APerson But this seems to be some bare metal / freestanding application, in which case non-portable/non-standard constructs are not that uncommon.

Comment: Having a custom NULL is not undefined behaviour, but will tend to introduce conflicts with standard headers (particularly standard C headers) - for example, if both the custom `NULL` and the one in standard headers are both macros (although the header linked by APerson does *try* to mitigate that).   The worse thing is that developers won't automatically/naturally assume that a project (or headers it uses) will have a tailored `NULL` so will be subtly misled about what code in that project does.  Misleading developers is a good way to introduce maintenance concerns and/or hard-to-find bugs.